# Why this function appears to have a singularity at each positive integer?

Tags: binomial-coefficients, smooth-functions

For fixed $l\in \mathbb Z_+$ and $\alpha\in \mathbb R$, define a function
$$p_l(\alpha) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom \alpha k \binom{-\alpha}{k+l} e^{-2k}.$$
Due to the exponential suppression $e^{-2k}$, the summation seems to be convergent, which is checked numerically.

By numerical investigation, I found out that $p_l(\alpha)$ has a singularity where $\alpha\in \mathbb Z_{>0}$. The following is the overall graph of $p_{12}(\alpha)$ after fixing $l=12$:

[image]

It appears as a smooth function, but when we zoom in near the integers, I found small singularity as marked in green. In all figures, $\alpha$ is zoomed near $-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7$. All horizontal axes are $\alpha$ and all vertical axes are $p_{12}(\alpha)$.

[image]

Although the amount of singularity (variation of $p_{12}(\alpha)$) is small, I believe this is larger than the precision that I use. **Is this singularity real, or is it just a numerical artifact?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Gaussian hypergeometric function
$$p_l(\alpha) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom \alpha k \binom{-\alpha}{k+l} e^{-2k}=\binom{-\alpha }{l} \, _2F_1\left(-\alpha ,l+\alpha ;l+1;\frac{1}{e^2}\right)$$ which has discontinuities at negative integer values of $l$.

Have a look [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Plot%5BHypergeometric2F1%5B-12%2C+l+%2B+12%2C+1+%2B+l%2C+E%5E%28-2%29%5D%2C%7Bl%2C-10%2C0%7D%5D).